# Google Maps API button that changes road to street view

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Currently I am outputting 2 google maps on the page, the first outputs the normal road map view, the second, street view.

Is there a way that I could load only one instance of a Google map but when clicking on a button, it'll toggle to street view?

Comment: Yes, there is.  How are you currently displaying the map/StreetView?

Comment: It's all good worked it out :) See answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out it out by declaring a var `panorama` and set to `setVisible` on click of button:

```
var panorama = map.getStreetView();
      panorama.setPosition(latlng);
      panorama.setPov({
          heading: 45,
          pitch:-10}
      );
    $("#myBtn").on('click', function(){
            panorama.setVisible(true);
    });
```